# Algorithm Analysis - Proof of Anonymous Function

Tags: algorithm, formula, analysis, inequality

Based on the definition of Big-Theta (or Big-O), how do I go about solving/proving an equation of this format: `An^2+ Θ(n) = Θ(n^B) where A and B are some constants` (i.e. there is an O(n) on both sides).

I know how to solve/prove Big-O and Big-Omega, but I'm completely lost on how to find c1, c2 and n when an anonymous function is involved.

An example of both Big-O and Big-Theta would be appreciated (lets use A=2, and B=2 for both examples).

Comment: `An^2 + Theta(n)` is NOT in `Theta(n^B)` unless B = 2.

Comment: @MitchWheat Unless there is a way of applying it I'm not aware of, the master theorem gives the asymptotic complexity for some recurrence relation, but here aren't any recurrence relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `An^2 + Theta(n)` is in `Theta(n^B)` if and only if `B == 2`.

Let's assume it from now on.

From definition of Big Theta, we know that Theta(n) is also O(n), and thus there is c1 and N1 such that for all n > N1: `An^2 + Theta(n) <= An^2 + c1*n`.

We also know that there are c2,N2 such that for all n>N2 `An^2 + c1*n <= c2*n^2`. We just got that by definition of big O - `An^2 + Theta(n)` is in `O(n^2)` (with the constant `c2` and `N=max(N1,N2)`), Similarly show for Omega(n^2), and you have shown `An^2 + Theta(n)` is in `Theta(n^2)` by definition.